# Strange URLs appearing in analytics and search console

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

Both in search console, and in Google analytics, I'll get users browsing to pages like:

/eeslqeqb79/kelompok-cerita-dewasa-swiss-foto-gambar-video.php
/eeslqeqb79/ver-peliculas-gratis-en-espanol-latino-de-estrenos-2016-por--gnula.php

And there are 100s of people finding these on my site, even tho they don't exist. I've checked search console and I have no issues (apparently).
A little help on what these are and how I can remove them will be most appreciated.

Comment: What CMS are you using? WP?

Comment: FTP into your site and browse around. l'll bet those files are there.

Answer (score 2):

Your site has been hacked. Check your server files (through your control panel for example) and you will most likely find those new directories there. (eeslqeqb79/)

Comment: It is often not this easy. For example, a hacked WP site. Can you explain more?

Comment: It doesn't have to be wordpress, it can be any CMS. Deleting the bad folders won't solve the problem though. Most likely the index.php of the template & .htaccess files have been corrupted as well to re-install the hacked pages.
Everything will need to be cleaned out and re-installed using  a clean backup. If the hacks come back then it could be an issue of a theme or plugin that has been compromised. (http://www.yangilbert.com/why-your-wordpress-site-is-getting-hacked)

Comment: I realize this. I did say ... for example. And hence why your answer is overly simplified. Generally, we ask for more information in a comment before answering. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you navigated to the urls (be cautious when doing so though) to see if they are actual pages?

It looks like it's quite likely your server is hacked, and is being used as an endpoint for scams.

You should login to the system and check if the file exist, if they do you should delete them and change your password for the console, ssh, ftp etc. You may also want to contact your server hosting company to alert them of what happened and see if they have any tips for you.

EDIT:

if they dont exist, there is a good chance that they are people trying to visit pages on a site that was running on the domain before you owned it. In that case you could safely ignore those hits.

Answer (score 1):

You have not been hacked, but spammed. Spammers can ad these kind of data to your analytics, hoping you click one url to find out more about it. They do it by sending data to randomly generated Analytics ID. Not much you can do about it; some people are suggesting methods invlolving filters, but not realy convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You site seems to have been hacked, I had similar issue with one of the WP website when hacker exploited one of the plugin. I came to know about it when google search show this WP website with message saying something related to .." THis website may have been compromised" I had to clean up teh whole website and resubmit the case to google and after 2 weeks and two review message was removed.

My issue was similar to your as random links where being generated from WP website. You have to work hard to find the source or plugin that is generating this issue. I am not a WP guy but managed to clean up the website. You can download the whole website and use multiple antivirus & malware detection to find the source. also you can compare it with your old backup to see what files have been added or modified.