# These files aren't on my server. How are they showing in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, hacked-site

I'm trying to understand how this is possible. The screenshot below shows two page views. both are .html files, but my site has ZERO .html files in it. My site also does not have a `/h/` directory.

My entire site consists of static .php files within one main directory (not `/h/`). The only reason .php is used is to pull in common navigation and ad placements. No pages are created dynamically and there is no admin panel. Everything is created on my workstation and uploaded.

I'm trying to figure out if my site was hacked or what could cause this to happen. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting support and what did they tell about this? Usually they can run a scan and also you can check the log files to know more information.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105350/strange-urls-appearing-in-analytics-and-search-console/105428

Comment: From my understanding of how Google Analytics works you put some javascript on your page and that code will report views directly from the client to Google without involving your server. As such it would be trivial for a client to report fake views to Google. Additional if you include that javascript on your 404 page even legitimate clients might report views on non-existing pages to Google.

Comment: 404 was my first thought too. In our site a 404 will appear at the requested URL, so we'll have legitimate hits to nonexistent page URLs. We have to switch to Page Title to see which hits are 404s. How nonexistent pages are getting requested in the first place would still be a question, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about your web server, your first call should be the log files. If it was a hit to your web server, you will see it in the access logs.

However, it could also just be tracking code re-use. Someone else made a site, copied your tracking code, and accessed those two pages on their own server. Google Analytics allows you to use the same code across multiple domains, so all this traffic will appear in the default "All Web Site Data" view for the property.

To eliminate this as a possibility, try [adding a filtered view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823) that only includes your domain.

Comment: Thank you NightSicarius, I'm adding filters now and testing it. I was not aware that hits from 3rd party domains could appear in my analytics reports. To me, this is the most logical reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons that could happen. Those are the steps to try to find out the problem:

1. **Stolen code**: use a filter to [add the hostname to Analytics](https://www.annielytics.com/blog/analytics/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/), then check if another domain is sending hits to your property. If that is the problem, add a filter to include only data from your domain.
2. **Virtual pageviews**: check if there is a plugin or addon which is using [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications?hl=en#tracking_virtual_pageviews) to generate hits that are not associated to real pages from your site. If that's happening, there is no problem, just ignore them or use a filter to exclude them from your view.
3. **Your site has been hacked**: check your FTP for recent unauthorized changes and your server log to find any strange HTTP requests. Also, use [Google Security Issues Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/security-issues) and [Google Fetch Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) to check if there is injected code in your final HTML.